# can’t find variable self

Tags: node.js, firebase, expo

I want to get a firebase token from expo and have to send that token to node js, using that I have to send push notifications.
Whenever I run the below code it shows unhandled promise rejection: reference error: can't find variable: self

```
  import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/messaging';
export default class App extends React.Component {
   async componentDidMount(){

      const config = {

        apiKey: "xxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxx",
        projectId: "xxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxx",
      debug: true
      };
     firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.messaging().getToken()
  .then(fcmToken => {
    if (fcmToken) {
      // user has a device token
      console.log("check for tokens",fcmToken)
    } else {
      console.log("err")
      // user doesn't have a device token yet
    } 
  });


}
render() {
    return (

        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>

    );
  }

  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please post code?

Comment: I tried using , firebase.messaging().getToken()
  .then(fcmToken => {
    if (fcmToken) {
      // user has a device token
    } else {
      // user doesn't have a device token yet
    } 
  });
But it throws error

Comment: Post the and format the coda in a readable way for other users to see and the exact error message you get.... It is really vague and hard to understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Hi squeekyDave,
I edit my question . Plz have a look

Comment: There's no variable `self` in the code you have here.  Usually that deals with function scoping issues i.e. `var self = this`.